# Pandas Data frame group by one column whilst multiplying others

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python with pandas imported to manipulate some data from a csv file I have.  Just playing around to try and learn something new.

I have the following data frame:

[image: Image of Data Frame]

I would like to group the data by col1 so that I get the following result.  Which is a `groupby` on col1 and col3 and col4 multiplied together.

[image: Image of result I would like]

I have been watching some youtube videos and reading some similar questions on stack overflow but I am having trouble.  So far I have the following which involves creating a new Col to hold the result of Col3 x Col4:

```
df['Col5'] = df.Col3 * df.Col4
gf = df.groupby(['col1', 'Col5'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use solution without creating new column, you can multiple columns and aggregate by column `df['Col1']` with aggregate `sum`, it is [*`syntactic sugar`*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby):

```
gf = (df.Col3 * df.Col4).groupby(df['Col1']).sum().reset_index(name='Col2')
print (gf)
    Col1     Col2
0  12345    38.64
1  23456  2635.10
2  45678   419.88
```

Another solution is possible create index by `Col1` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), multiple columns by [`prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) and last `sum` by index by `level=0`:

```
gf = df.set_index('Col1')[['Col3','Col4']].prod(axis=1).sum(level=0).reset_index(name='Col2')
```

Comment: This also appears to work but my result looks odd. it shows the results in this format: 1.837280e+03.  Can I display it as a real number?

Comment: @Silentbob - Maybe values to big for intigers, how working `gf['Col2'] = gf['Col2'].astype(np.int64)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Almost, but you are grouping by too many columns in the end. Try:

```
gf = df.groupby('Col1')['Col5'].sum()
```

Or to get it as a dataframe, rather than `Col1` as an index (I'm judging that this is what you want from your image), include `as_index=False` in your groupby:

```
gf = df.groupby('Col1', as_index=False)['Col5'].sum()
```

Comment: This appears to work but by result looks odd.   it shows the results in this format: 1.837280e+03